# Infinite scroll : good callback for comment inline plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, callback, jquery-callback

I use the plugin Infinite Scroll for wordpress and it works well.
But i also use the plugin Inline Ajax Comment which display comments in ajax on each post.

It does not work for the posts in the Infinite Scroll because the script need a callback.

So i use this callback :
    ajaxLoadedCallback();

Because in the script.js of inline comments, i can see :

```
// BETA: If newly loaded Ajax content has javascript then execute.
// This helps inline-ajax-comments work if loaded by something like Infinite Scroll.
// You MUST run this callback after ajax success. see jQuery docs.

function ajaxLoadedCallback() {
  scriptx = document.getElementsByTagName("script");


scripts = new Array();
for (var idx=0; idx<scriptx.length; idx++) {

    if (jQuery(scriptx[idx]).is(".inline-comments-script")) {
        scripts.push(scriptx[idx].innerHTML);
    }

}
```

But the comments are not loading...

Does someone got an idea ?

Thanks.

Inline Ajax Comments : http://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-ajax-comments/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer for your question.But I have a solution for your problem of inline comment .Check http://annote.in , to add annotation options on your blog. It works seamlessly on any platform and is being mostly adopted by ghost users.